# Prevent Empty Game Room in Unity Network Lobby from Destroying

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Software: Unity 2018.1
Language: C# 4
Plugin: Network Lobby

Problem/Question:

I have my Unity Network Lobby setup and working. I'm trying to prevent the Game Room from Destroying when all players leave the room or disconnect so that it can always be returned to at a later time.

Attempts: 
I tried changing `int i = 0` to into `i = -1` (Didn't work, no affect)
I tried changing `if (p != null)` to `if (p == null)` (Didn't work, no affect)
I tried silencing the code as well with 'Command, /'.  (Didn't work, no affect)

Here's the Code:

```
 public override void OnLobbyServerPlayerRemoved(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            LobbyPlayer p = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer;

            if (p != null)
            {
                p.RpcUpdateRemoveButton();
                p.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers + 1 >= minPlayers);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnLobbyServerDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            LobbyPlayer p = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer;

            if (p != null)
            {
                p.RpcUpdateRemoveButton();
                p.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers >= minPlayers);
            }
        }

    }
```

Complete Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Types;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Match;
using System.Collections;


namespace Prototype.NetworkLobby
{
public class LobbyManager : NetworkLobbyManager 
{
    static short MsgKicked = MsgType.Highest + 1;

    static public LobbyManager s_Singleton;


    [Header("Unity UI Lobby")]
    [Tooltip("Time in second between all players ready & match start")]
    public float prematchCountdown = 5.0f;

    [Space]
    [Header("UI Reference")]
    public LobbyTopPanel topPanel;

    public RectTransform mainMenuPanel;
    public RectTransform lobbyPanel;

    public LobbyInfoPanel infoPanel;
    public LobbyCountdownPanel countdownPanel;
    public GameObject addPlayerButton;

    protected RectTransform currentPanel;

    public Button backButton;

    public Text statusInfo;
    public Text hostInfo;

    //Client numPlayers from NetworkManager is always 0, so we count 
(throught connect/destroy in LobbyPlayer) the number
    //of players, so that even client know how many player there is.
    [HideInInspector]
    public int _playerNumber = 0;

    //used to disconnect a client properly when exiting the matchmaker
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool _isMatchmaking = false;

    protected bool _disconnectServer = false;

    protected ulong _currentMatchID;

    protected LobbyHook _lobbyHooks;

    void Start()
    {
        s_Singleton = this;
        _lobbyHooks = GetComponent<Prototype.NetworkLobby.LobbyHook>();
        currentPanel = mainMenuPanel;

        backButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        SetServerInfo("Offline", "None");
    }

    public override void OnLobbyClientSceneChanged(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetSceneAt(0).name == lobbyScene)
        {
            if (topPanel.isInGame)
            {
                ChangeTo(lobbyPanel);
                if (_isMatchmaking)
                {
                    if (conn.playerControllers[0].unetView.isServer)
                    {
                        backDelegate = StopHostClbk;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        backDelegate = StopClientClbk;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (conn.playerControllers[0].unetView.isClient)
                    {
                        backDelegate = StopHostClbk;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        backDelegate = StopClientClbk;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
            }

            topPanel.ToggleVisibility(true);
            topPanel.isInGame = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeTo(null);

            Destroy(GameObject.Find("MainMenuUI(Clone)"));

            //backDelegate = StopGameClbk;
            topPanel.isInGame = true;
            topPanel.ToggleVisibility(false);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeTo(RectTransform newPanel)
    {
        if (currentPanel != null)
        {
            currentPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (newPanel != null)
        {
            newPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        currentPanel = newPanel;

        if (currentPanel != mainMenuPanel)
        {
            backButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            backButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            SetServerInfo("Offline", "None");
            _isMatchmaking = false;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayIsConnecting()
    {
        var _this = this;
        infoPanel.Display("Connecting...", "Cancel", () => { _this.backDelegate(); });
    }

    public void SetServerInfo(string status, string host)
    {
        statusInfo.text = status;
        hostInfo.text = host;
    }


    public delegate void BackButtonDelegate();
    public BackButtonDelegate backDelegate;
    public void GoBackButton()
    {
        backDelegate();
        topPanel.isInGame = false;
    }

    // ----------------- Server management

    public void AddLocalPlayer()
    {
        TryToAddPlayer();
    }

    public void RemovePlayer(LobbyPlayer player)
    {
        player.RemovePlayer();
    }

    public void SimpleBackClbk()
    {
        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
    }

    public void StopHostClbk()
    {
        if (_isMatchmaking)
        {
            matchMaker.DestroyMatch((NetworkID)_currentMatchID, 0, OnDestroyMatch);
            _disconnectServer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            StopHost();
        }


        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
    }

    public void StopClientClbk()
    {
        StopClient();

        if (_isMatchmaking)
        {
            StopMatchMaker();
        }

        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
    }

    public void StopServerClbk()
    {
        StopServer();
        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
    }

    class KickMsg : MessageBase { }
    public void KickPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        conn.Send(MsgKicked, new KickMsg());
    }




    public void KickedMessageHandler(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        infoPanel.Display("Kicked by Server", "Close", null);
        netMsg.conn.Disconnect();
    }

    //===================

    public override void OnStartHost()
    {
        base.OnStartHost();

        ChangeTo(lobbyPanel);
        backDelegate = StopHostClbk;
        SetServerInfo("Hosting", networkAddress);
    }

    public override void OnMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
    {
        base.OnMatchCreate(success, extendedInfo, matchInfo);
        _currentMatchID = (System.UInt64)matchInfo.networkId;
    }

    public override void OnDestroyMatch(bool success, string extendedInfo)
    {
        base.OnDestroyMatch(success, extendedInfo);
        if (_disconnectServer)
        {
            StopMatchMaker();
            StopHost();
        }
    }

    //allow to handle the (+) button to add/remove player
    public void OnPlayersNumberModified(int count)
    {
        _playerNumber += count;

        int localPlayerCount = 0;
        foreach (PlayerController p in ClientScene.localPlayers)
            localPlayerCount += (p == null || p.playerControllerId == -1) ? 0 : 1;

        addPlayerButton.SetActive(localPlayerCount < maxPlayersPerConnection && _playerNumber < maxPlayers);
    }

    // ----------------- Server callbacks ------------------

    //we want to disable the button JOIN if we don't have enough player
    //But OnLobbyClientConnect isn't called on hosting player. So we override the lobbyPlayer creation
    public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateLobbyPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(lobbyPlayerPrefab.gameObject) as GameObject;

        LobbyPlayer newPlayer = obj.GetComponent<LobbyPlayer>();
        newPlayer.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers + 1 >= minPlayers);


        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            LobbyPlayer p = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer;

            if (p != null)
            {
                p.RpcUpdateRemoveButton();
                p.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers + 1 >= minPlayers);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public override void OnLobbyServerPlayerRemoved(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            LobbyPlayer p = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer;

            if (p != null)
            {
                p.RpcUpdateRemoveButton();
                p.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers + 1 >= minPlayers);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnLobbyServerDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            LobbyPlayer p = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer;

            if (p != null)
            {
                p.RpcUpdateRemoveButton();
                p.ToggleJoinButton(numPlayers >= minPlayers);
            }
        }

    }

    public override bool OnLobbyServerSceneLoadedForPlayer(GameObject lobbyPlayer, GameObject gamePlayer)
    {
        //This hook allows you to apply state data from the lobby-player to the game-player
        //just subclass "LobbyHook" and add it to the lobby object.

        if (_lobbyHooks)
            _lobbyHooks.OnLobbyServerSceneLoadedForPlayer(this, lobbyPlayer, gamePlayer);

        return true;
    }

    // --- Countdown management

    public override void OnLobbyServerPlayersReady()
    {
        bool allready = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(lobbySlots[i] != null)
                allready &= lobbySlots[i].readyToBegin;
        }

        if(allready)
            StartCoroutine(ServerCountdownCoroutine());
    }

    public IEnumerator ServerCountdownCoroutine()
    {
        float remainingTime = prematchCountdown;
        int floorTime = Mathf.FloorToInt(remainingTime);

        while (remainingTime > 0)
        {
            yield return null;

            remainingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            int newFloorTime = Mathf.FloorToInt(remainingTime);

            if (newFloorTime != floorTime)
            {//to avoid flooding the network of message, we only send a notice to client when the number of plain seconds change.
                floorTime = newFloorTime;

                for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (lobbySlots[i] != null)
                    {//there is maxPlayer slots, so some could be == null, need to test it before accessing!
                        (lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer).RpcUpdateCountdown(floorTime);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lobbySlots.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (lobbySlots[i] != null)
            {
                (lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer).RpcUpdateCountdown(0);
            }
        }

        ServerChangeScene(playScene);
    }

    // ----------------- Client callbacks ------------------

    public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        base.OnClientConnect(conn);

        infoPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        conn.RegisterHandler(MsgKicked, KickedMessageHandler);

        if (!NetworkServer.active)
        {//only to do on pure client (not self hosting client)
            ChangeTo(lobbyPanel);
            //backDelegate = StopClientClbk;
            SetServerInfo("Client", networkAddress);
        }
    }


    public override void OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        base.OnClientDisconnect(conn);
        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
    }

    public override void OnClientError(NetworkConnection conn, int errorCode)
    {
        ChangeTo(mainMenuPanel);
        infoPanel.Display("Cient error : " + (errorCode == 6 ? "timeout" : errorCode.ToString()), "Close", null);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to re-think the concept.

If you want to keep a "reference" to the last scene, you should save the state of your scene in some static manner (json?) or at least in a variable-gameObject.

You won't to keep "OnDestroyOnLoad" your scene, cause it's a waste of resources.

But, if you still want, I'll recommend you to use the additive way to load scenes. So you load the new scene into additive way, and disable the objects of the last scene.

**Additive Mode:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html

**Disable GameObjects:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Comment: Thanks Alex. I’m trying to create a database using Network Lobby; one where users can enter any room they want.

Comment: I don't know who is Alex, but if this answer helps you, mark it as answered please ^^ btw, I don't think that network lobby is the best approach to achieve what u want, but this can be another thread :D